# Product in java, does not give me the expected result

Tags: java

good afternoon, I am solving exercises and I ran into a problem, this is the statement:

Write a program that prints the product of all integer numbers from a to b ( a < b).
Include a and exclude b from the product.

And my code is like this

```
        int a = in.nextInt(), b = in.nextInt();
    long result = a;
    for (long i = a; i < b; i++) {
        result *= i  ;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

It tells me that it does not work since when trying that of these values:
Sample Input:

1 2

Sample Output:

1

Sample Input:

100 105

Sample Output:

11035502400

The first one works perfectly, but the second one prints me 1103550240000

I appreciate your help and your time;).

Comment: You have to set `result` initially to 1

Comment: It worked, thank you very much for your comments, take a while on this, thanks;), it was something simple, it usually happens hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the exercise does not want you to include the square a*a. This is a judgement based on your sample output in the second case being wrong by a factor of 100.

Try setting result to 1 initially.

Answer (score 2):

This is what your code is executing:
100*100*101*102*103*104 = 1103550240000

To achieve the correct answer, you need to eliminate a 100.

Try out the following:

```
        int a = in.nextInt(), b = in.nextInt();
    long result = a;
    long start = a;
    for (long i = a+1; i < b; i++) {
        if(start+1==b){
             result = result
        }
        else{
            result *= i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Of course, smart way to eliminate one multiplication step.

Comment: That way I tried, but it gave me an error in the part of entering 1 and 2, since it had to give result 1 and when jumping, it gave 2, the correct answer was to initialize the result in 1 but thanks the same for your time.

Comment: @arthuroali I'm a bit confused on how this produces result=2 in the case of a=1 b=2. The first loop sets i=2, checks if i<b (2<2 = false) meaning the loop shouldn't execute and should just return the result

Comment: Even in the case that it somehow did enter the loop, I edited it so that it would account for that case, by initializing another variable and comparing it to see if it is only 1 less than b, but as @plum 0 mentioned the loop should initialize in that case as i=2, 2<2, which would have skipped the loop entirely.